# How to send "ALT"+"S" in Rautomation?

Tags: ruby, rautomation

How can I send "ALT"+"s" keys to a window using RAutomation?  No info in Google at all.

Comment: Did you consider to open a issue on [github](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation)?

Comment: why? I don't even know if it is possible to send those keys.

Comment: I guess that the maintainer would be able to tell you if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you should be able to use `send_keys`.  The exact syntax depends on the selected adapter type.  These are the examples for the [`Win32`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rautomation/0.17.0/RAutomation/Adapter/Win32/Window#send_keys-instance_method) adapter:

```
RAutomation::Window.new(:title => //).send_keys "hello!"
RAutomation::Window.new(:title => //).send_keys [:control, "a"], "world!"
```

Comment: nope, did not work, getting error: NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for [:alt, "s"]:Array

Comment: The rdoc suggests referring "to specific Adapter documentation for all possible values".  You should check the docs for the adapter that you're using.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all defined special keys at [keys.rb](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/blob/537b50edaffeb77142f2c2678030f36b6b9a801e/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/keys.rb) and some [specs](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/blob/537b50edaffeb77142f2c2678030f36b6b9a801e/spec/adapter/win_32/window_spec.rb) of how to use them.

Looking at the specs, it seems that your example would be something like this:

`window.send_keys [:alt, "s"]`

Maybe you want to use `:left_alt` instead?